# How to upgrade minor version of angular using angular cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

This is a simple question but I'm struggling to find the answer via Google...

I have an angular 4 project (created using angular cli) and would like to make use of http interceptors that have just been released in 4.3.

How do I upgrade to this minor release using angular cli?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In my Angular CLI project I use `npm update` to update my dependencies. With `npm outdated`, you can see all outdated dependencies.

---

## Update June 2018

If you're using Angular CLI version 6+, you can use the new `ng update <packagename>` command to update your dependencies.

⚠️ This will update to the newest ***major*** version. If you don't want that stick with `npm update`. ⚠️

https://angular.io/guide/updating

> For simple updates, the CLI command `ng update` is all you need. Without additional arguments, `ng update` lists the updates that are available to you and provides recommended steps to update your application to the most current version.

Comment: Ahhh yes. npm outdated is useful too!

Comment: It's not updating package.json, any ideas?

Comment: If you upgrade to npm 5, you don't have to type --save anymore; it becomes the default. Makes life much easier. :)
see http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500

Comment: Should the ng update command update only minor versions? It upgraded the major version for me (from 7.2.0 to 8.0.0).

Comment: @TrevorKarjanis Yes, this will also update the major version (and performing most code changes necessary for the update). I've edited the post to reflect that. If you want to stick to the same major version, use `npm update` and make sure to have the corresponding version range in your `package.json`: see https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004

Answer (score 62):

Major version angular updates should be done with **ng update**.

`npm update` for updating angular minor/patch versions has a downside: it will also update other unrelated packages.

You can use **[npm-check-updates](https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates)** to update just specific packages and you can choose to target patch/minor/major versions.

This command will update all angular package minor (and patch) versions (but it will keep the major versions):

`npx npm-check-updates --upgrade --target "minor" --filter "/@angular.*/"`

That command gives you a preview of the new versions and updates the package.json accordingly:

[image]

Afterwards you can run `npm install`.

Comment: This one is pretty handy for minor updates thx !

Comment: This is an amazing command. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For me, upgrading from Angular 16.0.0 to 16.1.6 could just be done with:

`ng update @angular/cli@16 @angular/core@16`

Answer (score -1):

In some cases `ng update` doesn't update the angular core dependencies with minor version updates.

I've faced a case trying to update from Angular 6.0.0 to 6.1.0, and it didn't work.

I solved this only doing the steps:

1. Delete the project `node_modules` directory
2. Change manually in the `package.json` all the angular core dependencies libraries:

   ```
   common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
   platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
   ```

   Like the last 4 lines here:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
       "@agm/core": "~1.0.0-beta.3",
       "@angular/animations": "^6.0.9",
       "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.0",
       "@angular/cli": "^6.2.9",
       "@angular/common": "^6.1.x",
       "@angular/core": "^6.1.x",
       "@angular/forms": "^6.1.x",
       "@angular/http": "^6.1.x",
   ```

   See in the `devdependencies` for `compiler, compiler-cli` too.
3. Run `npm install` to rebuild `node_modules`.
4. After this we have the result of `ng --version` cli command from 6.0.0 to 6.1.10.